# path to assets in Wordpress using jQuery

Tags: jquery, wordpress, coffeescript

Hi i'm trying to replace the add to cart button by a loading image in jquery but I can't seem to find the write path using jquery.

This is my code in coffee:

```
$('.add_to_cart_button').click ->
    templateDir = "<?php bloginfo('template_directory') ?>"
    ajaxImage = document.createElement("img")
    ajaxImage.setAttribute("src", templateDir + "/static/img/ajax-loader.gif")
    $(@).replaceWith(ajaxImage)
```

this outputs in the DOM :

```
 <img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory') ?>/static/img/ajax-loader.gif">
```

anybody know how to put in the right path ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you're writing php code in a javascript document.

id suggest in your header.php put this code

```
<script>var templateDir = '<?php echo get_bloginfo('template_directory');?>';</script>
```